# How to find 12 consecutive transactions

Tags: sql, sql-server, transactions, row-number

I have a table below.

[image]

I'm looking for a 12 months consecutive transactions (which are highlighted by yellow, orange and green). For the green there are 2 transactions for month 06/2013, however it compensates the transactions for 07/2013 since it's missing. There are also some transactions where there are more then 2 transactions for a month-year but they can be compensated for other missing transactions.

Below is the query to construct the table.

```
CREATE TABLE #Temp 
( 
  ProductProvider  VARCHAR(200),
  ProductType  VARCHAR(200),
  PolicyID BIGINT, 
  TransactionDate DATE, 
  TotalRevenue DECIMAL(10,2)
 )
 --DROP TABLE #temp
insert into #Temp
values
('XYZ',     'ONG',  2789753,    '2009-04-30',   0.19)
,('XYZ',    'ONG',  2789753,    '2009-05-31',   0.19)
,('XYZ',    'ONG',  2789753,    '2009-07-31',   0.19)
,('XYZ',    'ONG',  2789753,    '2009-08-31',   0.19)
,('XYZ',    'ONG',  2789753,    '2009-10-31',   0.19)
,('XYZ',    'ONG',  2789753,    '2009-11-30',   0.19)
,('XYZ',    'ONG',  2789753,    '2009-12-31',   0.19)
,('XYZ',    'ONG',  2789753,    '2010-01-31',   0.19)
,('XYZ',    'ONG',  2789753,    '2010-02-28',   0.19)
,('XYZ',    'ONG',  2789753,    '2010-03-31',   0.19)
,('XYZ',    'ONG',  2789753,    '2010-04-30',   0.19)
,('XYZ',    'ONG',  2789753,    '2010-05-31',   0.19)
,('XYZ',    'ONG',  2789753,    '2010-06-30',   0.19)
,('XYZ',    'ONG',  2789753,    '2010-07-31',   0.19)
,('XYZ',    'ONG',  2789753,    '2010-08-31',   0.19)
,('XYZ',    'ONG',  2789753,    '2010-09-30',   0.19)
,('XYZ',    'ONG',  2789753,    '2010-10-30',   0.19)
,('XYZ',    'ONG',  2789753,    '2011-01-31',   0.19)
,('XYZ',    'ONG',  2789753,    '2011-02-28',   0.19)
,('XYZ',    'ONG',  2789753,    '2011-04-30',   0.19)
,('XYZ',    'ONG',  2789753,    '2011-05-31',   0.19)
,('XYZ',    'ONG',  2789753,    '2011-06-30',   0.19)
,('XYZ',    'ONG',  2789753,    '2011-07-31',   0.19)
,('XYZ',    'ONG',  2789753,    '2011-08-31',   0.19)
,('XYZ',    'ONG',  2789753,    '2011-10-31',   0.19)
,('XYZ',    'ONG',  2789753,    '2011-12-31',   0.19)
,('XYZ',    'ONG',  2789753,    '2012-05-31',   0.19)
,('XYZ',    'ONG',  2789753,    '2012-06-30',   0.19)
,('XYZ',    'ONG',  2789753,    '2012-07-31',   0.19)
,('XYZ',    'ONG',  2789753,    '2012-08-31',   0.19)
,('XYZ',    'ONG',  2789753,    '2012-09-30',   0.19)
,('XYZ',    'ONG',  2789753,    '2012-10-31',   0.19)
,('XYZ',    'ONG',  2789753,    '2012-11-30',   0.19)
,('XYZ',    'ONG',  2789753,    '2012-12-31',   0.19)
,('XYZ',    'ONG',  2789753,    '2013-01-31',   0.19)
,('XYZ',    'ONG',  2789753,    '2013-02-28',   0.19)
,('XYZ',    'ONG',  2789753,    '2013-03-31',   0.19)
,('XYZ',    'ONG',  2789753,    '2013-04-30',   0.19)
,('XYZ',    'ONG',  2789753,    '2013-05-31',   0.19)
,('XYZ',    'ONG',  2789753,    '2013-06-25',   0.19)
,('XYZ',    'ONG',  2789753,    '2013-06-30',   0.19)
,('XYZ',    'ONG',  2789753,    '2013-08-31',   0.19)
,('XYZ',    'ONG',  2789753,    '2013-09-30',   0.19)
,('XYZ',    'ONG',  2789753,    '2013-10-31',   0.19)
,('XYZ',    'ONG',  2789753,    '2013-11-30',   0.19)
,('XYZ',    'ONG',  2789753,    '2013-12-31',   0.19)
,('XYZ',    'ONG',  2789753,    '2014-01-31',   0.19)
,('XYZ',    'ONG',  2789753,    '2014-02-28',   0.19)
,('XYZ',    'ONG',  2789753,    '2014-03-31',   0.19)
,('XYZ',    'ONG',  2789753,    '2014-04-30',   0.19)
,('XYZ',    'ONG',  2789753,    '2014-08-30',   0.19)
```

Below is my first try.

```
select *
from (select t.*, 
             count(*) over (partition by ProductProvider, ProductType, TotalRevenue, DATEADD(m,seqnum, convert(date, DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, TransactionDate), 0)))) as cnt_group
      from (select *,
                   row_number() over (partition by ProductProvider, ProductType, TotalRevenue order by convert(date, DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, TransactionDate), 0))) as seqnum
            from #Temp
           ) t
     ) t
where cnt_group = 12
order by transactiondate
```

I got nothing from the above query (I guess I can't row-numbering ProductProvider / ProductType / PolicyId since the transaction dates are all different, thus gives me row number 1 to 51 with no grouping).

Below is my second attempt.

```
SELECT DISTINCT *,
       month1+month2+month3+month4+month5+month6+month7+month8+month9+month10+month11+month12 AS Total
FROM 
    (
    SELECT a.*, 
           1 AS Month1, 
           CASE WHEN b.ProductProvider IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS Month2,
           CASE WHEN c.ProductProvider IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS Month3,
           CASE WHEN d.ProductProvider IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS Month4,
           CASE WHEN e.ProductProvider IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS Month5,
           CASE WHEN f.ProductProvider IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS Month6,
           CASE WHEN g.ProductProvider IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS Month7,
           CASE WHEN h.ProductProvider IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS Month8,
           CASE WHEN i.ProductProvider IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS Month9,
           CASE WHEN j.ProductProvider IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS Month10,
           CASE WHEN k.ProductProvider IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS Month11,
           CASE WHEN l.ProductProvider IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS Month12
    FROM #Temp a
    LEFT JOIN #temp b ON a.ProductProvider = b.ProductProvider
                     AND a.ProductType = b.ProductType
                     AND a.policyid = b.policyid
                     AND convert(date, DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, b.TransactionDate), 0)) = DATEADD(m, 1, convert(date, DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, a.TransactionDate), 0)))
    LEFT JOIN #temp c ON a.ProductProvider = c.ProductProvider
                     AND a.ProductType = c.ProductType
                     AND a.policyid = c.policyid
                     AND convert(date, DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, c.TransactionDate), 0)) = DATEADD(m, 2, convert(date, DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, a.TransactionDate), 0)))
    LEFT JOIN #temp d ON a.ProductProvider = d.ProductProvider
                     AND a.ProductType = d.ProductType
                     AND a.policyid = d.policyid
                     AND convert(date, DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, d.TransactionDate), 0)) = DATEADD(m, 3, convert(date, DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, a.TransactionDate), 0)))
    LEFT JOIN #temp e ON a.ProductProvider = e.ProductProvider
                     AND a.ProductType = e.ProductType
                     AND a.policyid = e.policyid
                     AND convert(date, DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, e.TransactionDate), 0)) = DATEADD(m, 4, convert(date, DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, a.TransactionDate), 0)))
    LEFT JOIN #temp f ON a.ProductProvider = f.ProductProvider
                     AND a.ProductType = f.ProductType
                     AND a.policyid = f.policyid
                     AND convert(date, DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, f.TransactionDate), 0)) = DATEADD(m, 5, convert(date, DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, a.TransactionDate), 0)))
    LEFT JOIN #temp g ON a.ProductProvider = g.ProductProvider
                     AND a.ProductType = g.ProductType
                     AND a.policyid = g.policyid
                     AND convert(date, DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, g.TransactionDate), 0)) = DATEADD(m, 6, convert(date, DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, a.TransactionDate), 0)))
    LEFT JOIN #temp h ON a.ProductProvider = h.ProductProvider
                     AND a.ProductType = h.ProductType
                     AND a.policyid = h.policyid
                     AND convert(date, DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, h.TransactionDate), 0)) = DATEADD(m, 7, convert(date, DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, a.TransactionDate), 0)))
    LEFT JOIN #temp i ON a.ProductProvider = i.ProductProvider
                     AND a.ProductType = i.ProductType
                     AND a.policyid = i.policyid
                     AND convert(date, DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, i.TransactionDate), 0)) = DATEADD(m, 8, convert(date, DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, a.TransactionDate), 0)))
    LEFT JOIN #temp j ON a.ProductProvider = j.ProductProvider
                     AND a.ProductType = j.ProductType
                     AND a.policyid = j.policyid
                     AND convert(date, DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, j.TransactionDate), 0)) = DATEADD(m, 9, convert(date, DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, a.TransactionDate), 0)))
    LEFT JOIN #temp k ON a.ProductProvider = k.ProductProvider
                     AND a.ProductType = k.ProductType
                     AND a.policyid = k.policyid
                     AND convert(date, DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, k.TransactionDate), 0)) = DATEADD(m, 10, convert(date, DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, a.TransactionDate), 0)))
    LEFT JOIN #temp l ON a.ProductProvider = l.ProductProvider
                     AND a.ProductType = l.ProductType
                     AND a.policyid = l.policyid
                     AND convert(date, DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, l.TransactionDate), 0)) = DATEADD(m, 11, convert(date, DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, a.TransactionDate), 0)))
    ) x
```

My logic is if I can get 12 for the column total, that's the result that I will keep. However with this method it seems it's calculating 12 consecutive transactions per row (I guess the term is running 12 consecutive months). So check row 1 for 12 consecutive months, check row 2 for 12 consecutive months, check row 3 for 12 consecutive months, etc. At the end there is no clear indicator which 12 consecutive months that I can pick and remove from the #temp table so they will not be double-counted. Also this method doesn't work if there are more then 1 transactions on the same month-year that can compensate other missing transactions because it only counts 11 in total.

The last method is by using looping. So pick row number 1, check if there is 12 consecutive transactions, if not pick row 2, if not pick row 3, if yes, pick the date on row 3 up to the last 12th date from row 3 and put it somewhere and delete them from the table #temp. And then start the looping again. However due my limitation in constructing looping apart from simple looping like DO-WHILE-PRINT, I can't write any query for this.

I'm using Microsoft SQL 2012.

**17/08/2021** - I have another method below.

```
;WITH CTEDATES
AS
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY TransactionDate asc ) AS ROWNUMBER,* FROM #Temp  

),
 CTEDATES1
AS
(
   SELECT *, 1 as groupid FROM CTEDATES WHERE ROWNUMBER=1
   UNION ALL
   SELECT a.*,case datediff(m, b.transactiondate,a.transactiondate) when 1 then b.groupid else b.groupid+1 end as gap FROM CTEDATES A INNER JOIN CTEDATES1 B ON A.ROWNUMBER-1 = B.ROWNUMBER
)
, cte AS
(
select productprovider, producttype, policyid, totalrevenue, MIN(transactiondate) as startdate, max(transactiondate) as enddate from CTEDATES1 group by productprovider, producttype, policyid, totalrevenue,groupid
)
SELECT b.productprovider, 
     b.producttype, 
     b.policyid, 
     b.totalrevenue,a.startdate, a.enddate, COUNT(b.totalrevenue) AS TotalTransaction
FROM cte a
INNER JOIN #temp b ON a.productprovider = b.ProductProvider
                  AND a.producttype = b.ProductType
                  AND a.policyid = b.PolicyID
                  AND a.totalrevenue = b.totalrevenue
WHERE b.TransactionDate BETWEEN a.startdate AND a.enddate
GROUP BY b.productprovider, 
     b.producttype, 
     b.policyid, 
     b.totalrevenue, 
     a.startdate, 
     a.enddate
```

It can detect the gaps and the total transactions between those gaps, and at the end I can choose TotalTransactions >= 12 and apply another row_numbering to get exactly 12 consecutive transactions. However with this method, unfortunately it can't detect multiple transactions within the same month-year that more likely used to compensate the missing month-year. Below is the result.

[image]

The result from column 8 should be StartDate = 2012/05/31 and EndDate = 2014/04/30 with TotalTransaction = 24 since there are 2 transactions in the month-year 06/2013 which one of them is to compensate the missing transaction for month-year 07/2013.

**18/08/2021** - Another method below which works for this scenario only.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#AssigningNewTransactionDate') IS NOT NULL                                                
DROP TABLE #AssigningNewTransactionDate

;WITH cte AS
(
SELECT *, 
       CONVERT(date, DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, TransactionDate), 0)) AS FirstoftheMonth
FROM #temp
)
,cte2 AS
(
SELECT productprovider, producttype, policyid, totalrevenue, firstofthemonth, COUNT(firstofthemonth) AS NumberofFirstOfTheMonth
FROM cte           
GROUP BY productprovider, producttype, policyid, totalrevenue, firstofthemonth
)
, cte3 AS
(
SELECT a.*, 
       b.NumberofFirstOfTheMonth, 
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY a.productprovider, a.producttype, a.policyid, a.totalrevenue, a.firstofthemonth ORDER by a.firstofthemonth) AS Row_num
FROM cte a
LEFT JOIN cte2 b ON a.productprovider = b.ProductProvider
              AND a.producttype = b.ProductType
              AND a.policyid = b.PolicyID
              AND a.totalrevenue = b.TotalRevenue
              AND a.firstofthemonth = b.firstofthemonth
)
SELECT *, 
       CASE WHEN NumberofFirstOfTheMonth = 2 AND row_num = 1 AND LAG(firstofthemonth, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY productprovider, producttype, policyid, totalrevenue ORDER BY firstofthemonth) = DATEADD(m, -1, firstofthemonth) THEN cte3.TransactionDate
            WHEN NumberofFirstOfTheMonth = 2 AND row_num = 2 AND LAG(firstofthemonth, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY productprovider, producttype, policyid, totalrevenue ORDER BY firstofthemonth) = firstofthemonth THEN DATEADD(m, 1, transactiondate)
            ELSE cte3.TransactionDate
       END AS NewTransactionDate
INTO #AssigningNewTransactionDate
FROM cte3

;WITH CTEDATES
AS
    (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY NewTransactionDate asc ) AS ROWNUMBER,* 
    FROM #AssigningNewTransactionDate  
    )
, CTEDATES1
AS
    (
       SELECT *, 1 as groupid 
       FROM CTEDATES WHERE ROWNUMBER=1
       UNION ALL
       SELECT a.*,case datediff(m, b.newtransactiondate,a.newtransactiondate) when 1 then b.groupid else b.groupid+1 end as gap FROM CTEDATES A INNER JOIN CTEDATES1 B ON A.ROWNUMBER-1 = B.ROWNUMBER
    )
, cte AS
        (
        select productprovider, producttype, policyid, totalrevenue, MIN(newtransactiondate) as startdate, max(newtransactiondate) as enddate 
        FROM CTEDATES1 
        GROUP by productprovider, producttype, policyid, totalrevenue,groupid
        )
SELECT b.productprovider, 
     b.producttype, 
     b.policyid, 
     b.totalrevenue,a.startdate, a.enddate, COUNT(b.totalrevenue) AS TotalTransaction
FROM cte a
INNER JOIN #AssigningNewTransactionDate b ON a.productprovider = b.ProductProvider
                  AND a.producttype = b.ProductType
                  AND a.policyid = b.PolicyID
                  AND a.totalrevenue = b.totalrevenue
WHERE b.NewTransactionDate BETWEEN a.startdate AND a.enddate
GROUP BY b.productprovider, 
     b.producttype, 
     b.policyid, 
     b.totalrevenue, 
     a.startdate, 
     a.enddate
```

[image]

With this method, the missing transaction of 07/13 between ...05/13, 06/13, 06/13, 08/13 can be compensated by one the transaction on 06/13. However this method is not bullet-proof if another scenario where there are multiple transactions occur, like ...04, 06, 06, 07, 08... or ... 04, 07, 07, 07, 08...

Comment: The logic of  compensation is not quite clear. For example months are `..05, 07,07, 09..` What is the desired result, `..05,06,07` i.e. 06 is compensated or `07,08,09..`  i.e. 08 is compensated?

Comment: Hi Serg, for the compensation logic, it has to compensate the earliest month (since all the revenue are the same) for example if the months are ...05, 07, 07, 09... then one of the 07 month need to compensate the missing 06. So it will be ...05, 06, 07, 09... Thanks.

Comment: Does `...05, 07, 07, 07, 09...` compensate both 06 and 08?  What about `.. 04, 06, 07, 07, 08..` , is 05 compensated? The compensation rules should be specified in more details in the question.

Comment: Hi Serg, for ..05, 07, 07, 07, 09.. yes it compensate both 06 and 08. For .. 04, 06, 07, 07, 08.. yes it compensate 05. So the multiple transactions in the same month-year must compensate the first of the missing month. If it's .. 05, 07, 07, 09.. it will only compensate 06 and 08 will keep missing payment. 

I have updated the logic and posted it above. With LAG, I can create the CASE logic, however it only works for the scenario like ..05,06,06,08.. Is it possible to create "scenario grouping" using CASE (like scenario ..05, 06, 06, 08.. do this, scenario ..04,06, 07,07,08.. do this etc) ?

Answer (score 1):

From what I can tell, you want to know if there are 12 transactions in less than a year.

For that, you can use `lag()` or `lead()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             lag(transactionDate, 11) over (partition by ProductProvider, ProductType, PolicyId order by TransactionDate) as transactionDate_11
      from #temp t
     ) t
where transactionDate_11 > datedadd(year, -1, TransactionDate)
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon for your help. With this method unfortunately it will double counting the rows. For example the result TransactionDate = 2010/10/30 and TransactionDate_11 = 2009/11/30 should be excluded since 2009/11/30 is part of the 12 month range for the first result (TransactionDate 2010/09/30 and TransactionDate_11 2009/10/31). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Find starting dates followed by at least 11 rows within next 11 months.

```
select t.ProductProvider, t.ProductType, t.PolicyID, t.TransactionDate first_date, max(t2.TransactionDate) last_date
from #Temp t
join #Temp t2 on t.ProductProvider = t2.ProductProvider and  t.ProductType = t2.ProductType and t.PolicyID = t2.PolicyID
   and t2.TransactionDate > t.TransactionDate and datediff(month, t.TransactionDate, t2.TransactionDate) < 12
group by t.ProductProvider, t.ProductType, t.PolicyID, t.TransactionDate
having count(*) >= 11
```

Then you can list those following rows from the found start dates.

**EDIT**
To exclude overlapping intervals traverse the above result recursively, i.e.

```
with allIntv as (
  select t.ProductProvider, t.ProductType, t.PolicyID, t.TransactionDate first_date, max(t2.TransactionDate) last_date
  from #Temp t
  join #Temp t2 on t.ProductProvider = t2.ProductProvider and  t.ProductType = t2.ProductType and t.PolicyID = t2.PolicyID
     and t2.TransactionDate > t.TransactionDate and datediff(month, t.TransactionDate, t2.TransactionDate) < 12
  group by t.ProductProvider, t.ProductType, t.PolicyID, t.TransactionDate
  having count(*) >= 11 
), rcte as (
  -- the first interval
  select top(1) with ties t.*
  from allIntv t
  order by row_number() over(partition by t.ProductProvider, t.ProductType, t.PolicyID order by t.first_date)

  union all

  -- first non-overlapping interval
  -- TOP() is forbidden in the recursive part, using NOT EXISTS
  select t.*
  from allIntv t
  join rcte on t.first_date > rcte.last_date
     and not exists (select 1 
                     from allIntv t2
                     where t.ProductProvider = t2.ProductProvider and t.ProductType = t2.ProductType and t.PolicyID = t2.PolicyID
                        and t2.first_date > rcte.last_date and  t2.first_date < t.first_date)
)
select * 
from rcte;
```

For the OP sample data it returns

```
ProductProvider ProductType PolicyID    first_date  last_date
XYZ ONG 2789753 2009-10-31  2010-09-30
XYZ ONG 2789753 2012-05-31  2013-04-30
XYZ ONG 2789753 2013-05-31  2014-04-30
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=c8f035fdd7ef2918c11421acd5397f43)

Comment: Thanks for your help Serg. The drawback with this method is it will look for any rows with 12 months after the first_date. For example the first result is 2009/10/31 to 2010/09/30 - this is correct. However the second result is 2009/11/30 - 2010/30. This result should be excluded due to date 2009/11/30 already part of the range from the first result. So at the end, I only need to get all the dates between 2009/10/31 to 2010/09/30, 2012/05/31 to 2013/04/30, and 201305/31 to 2014/04/30.